# Closing a foreign network shared folder session

Tags: go

I'm fairly new to programming and I am learning with Go.  I want to rename a shared folder on my network, which I can do, but before doing so I want to ensure that no one has it open.  If anyone has the folder open I want to be able to close that session in my Go program. I combed through the Go packages and wasn't able to find anything.  Is it even possible with Go or will I need to call some plugin from my program?  Thanks!

Comment: Figuring out if anyone has a shared folder open might depend on how that folder is shared. How is it shared?

Comment: More to what @Schwern said, one must keep in mind that all operations related to filesystems (including networked) are inherently prone to races: by the time you figured out your folder is not open by anyone, it well may be already open.

Comment: If you're talking about Windows and its SMB (CIFS) protocol then you can use the WMI layer to ask the server about what its shares it has open by users. I guess there were packages to work with WMI; as a last resort, working with Win32 API calls in Go is relatively straightforward.

Comment: This is just a standard windows network share.  "Everyone" has full control

Comment: Thanks everyone, I actually was able to call psfile,exe with go.command

Comment: cmd := exec.Command(`psfile`, serverName, localPath, "-c")
err := cmd.Start()
//error handling